# Image as Plane OBJECTS move others without them being parented

Tags: animation, mesh, image, parent

This is my first time trying (basic) 2D animation in Blender. I advanced the animation last friday from home and I re-opened the file today at my office and this happens:

[Video Capture:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6SPcZpbvnj0JS9WxkriKLy2obLAKPv8/view?usp=sharing)

I'm opening this file now in Blender 3.5.0
I worked the file probably on another Blender version (not too old tho) I don't remember and can't check.

I'm making a 2D animation with Images as Planes. These are the imported settings I used:
(will only list the ones I did different from defaults)

- Material Type = Shadeless
- Plane Dimensions = Dpi / Definition = 600 (default)

In the video I show how some things are parented. However the objects that are moving each other ARE NOT PARENTED in any way. The main objects of interest to fix are:

- background (not parented to anything)
- proximamente_sign & screw (Parented to bastop_sing
- ear_front_inner (Parented to invisible_wheel/Hamster/ear_front

As shown in the video. However you can also see how when I move the object Hamster, all it's children move further than the parent object (the empty body looking image)

Things I tried:

- When I opened the file I noticed the Addon Import Images as Planes WAS NOT active. I thought it might be that so I installed it, deleted the file, and re-downloaded it BUT the problem persisted.
- Checked Relations in the Object Properties to see if maybe I had moved anything but apparently not.
- I tried deleting and re-importing these images. However when i do, they maintaing this "buggy parenting issue" behaviour (again, without them being parented at all)
- Since I am animating and blocking certain Transform options on certain objects, I tested if by unlocking the transforms on the *bastop_sign* to see if the *screw* and the *proximamente_sign* would move independantly, but it failed.
- When moving objects i also made sure to try being on the first frame of animation (frame cero)

I'm animating these 2D elements without a rig. I'm just keyframing positions and rotations on the objects. Maybe this is where I did wrong? I've animated 3D objects like this before with no issues. At this point I don't know if this is an Images to Planes or an animation bug. Or maybe a combination of these. Maybe something I did went wrong.

If anyone knows a solution to this, or has any idea on what else I can check to get a lead I'd really appreciate it.

PD. When I made the file I moved all the objects to different z positions to create my "layers", and objects were moving independently from each other. It is now that I have re-opened the file that everything when wrong.

For moving these objects and continuing my work I'm trying a workaround. I'm blocking these object's position transforms when moving a another object to the desired "layer" height. I'm still going to find out if I can animated these without issue. This is still a strange problem, so I will leave the question up. I'd still like to know if this is a bug and if there is a viable solution

**UPDATE: Yes, I had active the proportional editting tool**